# Binary search is not fast

Tags: java, algorithms, sorting

I am trying to put in practice an algorithm for binary searching and compare it with linear searching:

- linear search:

```java
public static int linearSearch(ArrayList<Book> books, int searchedId) {
    for (int i = 0; i < books.size(); i++) {
        int currId = books.get(i).getId();
        if (currId == searchedId) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

- and binary search

```java
public static int binarySearch(ArrayList<Book> books, long searchedId) {
    if (!isSorted(books)) {
        System.err.println("ArrayList must be sorted!");
        return -1;
    }

    int ix_st = 0;
    int ix_en = books.size() - 1;
    int middle = 0;
    while (ix_st <= ix_en) {
        middle = (ix_en + ix_st)/2;
        int currId = books.get(middle).getId();
        if (currId == searchedId) {
            return middle;
        }
        if (searchedId > currId) {
            ix_st = middle + 1;
        }
        if (searchedId < currId) {
            ix_en = middle - 1;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

[the whole code](https://gist.github.com/celdorwow/e47aed42606ccb486a9180fc12ca73e4)

but not only is the binary searching algorithm similar but sometimes even slower than a trivial linear searching. I can't understan why. Binary search is supposed to run the code only for ~log2(100,000) = 17 iterations or ~log2(1,000,000) = 20 iterations, whilst the linear searching is full looping thorugh for 1,000,000 iterations in the worst scenario. Obviously, the lists are sorted. I've got these timings:

```
How many books to create?
[Me] 100000
Id of the book to search for?
[Me] 987665

Searching with linear search:
The search took 9 milliseconds.
Book not found


Seaching with binary search:
The search took 13 milliseconds.
Book not found

Process finished with exit code 0
```

[the whole code](https://gist.github.com/celdorwow/e47aed42606ccb486a9180fc12ca73e4).

I am not sure if the compiler is optimising something in background. Then it would make sense. Any idea? Thanks.

PS. The code is from the MOOC.fi website as I am taking an online course from the University of Helsinki called [Java Programming I](https://java-programming.mooc.fi/), particularly from [this section](https://java-programming.mooc.fi/part-7/2-algorithms).

Comment: Also, if the 1 book you're looking for happens to be among the first, the linear search will outperform.  To get a better sense of the time, you would have to search for thousands of books, and average the times.

Comment: FYI, This binary search code has the classic [binary search overflow bug](https://thebittheories.com/the-curious-case-of-binary-search-the-famous-bug-that-remained-undetected-for-20-years-973e89fc212?gi=72db1108c538)

Comment: Using a debugger to step through your code would have shown you immediately what’s going on.

Answer (score 12):

Your actual binary search implementation includes a test `isSorted()` which scans through the whole list and is therefore slower than the linear search. Re-test without this and you will see different results.

Comment: Something like isSorted should be a property that gets invalidated on any modification of the array and checked only when invalid.

Comment: @gnasher729 or you drop it entirely and accept that `binarySearch` only has defined behaviour for sorted lists